# Dealing with polymorphic classes in Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api

For a search feature i have to implement a quite join heavy query to return all location based services from specified ranges (PLZAreaRange).
As you can see there are a lot of inheritance structures till i reach the PLZAreaRange to compare the search criteria with the plzText.

```
public abstract class LocationbasedService {
    @OneToOne
    private Geography geography;
}

public abstract class Geography {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="geography")
    private LocationbasedService locationbasedService;
}

public class Areageography extends Geography {
    @ManyToOne
    private Area from;
    @ManyToOne
    private Area to;

}

public abstract class Area {
}

public class PLZArea extends Area {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "plzArea")
    private List<PLZAreaRange> abschnitte = new ArrayList<PLZAreaRange>();

}

public class PLZAreaRange {

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private PLZArea plzArea;

    private String plzText;

}
```

How do i join down to this entity to select all Services which have the plzText in ("test1", "test2")?

greetings
m

Comment: some time criteria api makes some complexity , use `HQL` for simply joins.

Comment: I normally use hql, but it is a search query which has many optional parts. Building up the query within a string would make it very unreadable. Overcome the complexity with some views worked very well and the code is clean again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a view to reduce the query complexity. The inheritance boundary seemed to be a huge problem.